# PHP reflection; extracting non-block comments

Tags: php, reflection, comments, phpdoc

I've recently become familiar with `Reflection`, and have been experimenting with it, especially `getDocComment()`, however it appears that it only supports `/** */` comment blocks.

```
/** foobar */
class MyClass{}

$refl = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');

// produces /** foobar */
echo $refl->getDocComment();
```

-Versus-

```
# foobar
class MyClass{}

$refl = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');

// produces nothing
echo $refl->getDocComment();
```

Is it not possible to capture this without resorting to any sort of `file_get_contents(__FILE__)` nonsense?

---

As per **dader51**'s answer, I suppose my best approach would be something along these lines:

```
// random comment

#[annotation]

/**
 * another comment with a # hash
 */

#[another annotation]

$annotations
    = array_filter(token_get_all(file_get_contents(__FILE__)), function(&$token){
    return (($token[0] == T_COMMENT) && ($token = strstr($token[1], '#')));
});

print_r($annotations);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [4] => #[annotation]

    [8] => #[another annotation]

)
```

Comment: Regarding my edit; it's still infeasible. Microtime tested it against the `Zend_Controller_Front` class file, (*1007 lines, 3497 tokens*) and it takes `0.010729945898056` on average (*1000 iterations on my personal dev box*)

Comment: did you get that right ? was wondering if you found a better way.

Comment: @dader No, a straight text parse of a given file may yield better performance but then you need to make sense of the results.

Comment: ok, I would propose this one, it may or may not be feasible. Using a recursive descent parser you could write a simple grammar that shall only distinguish between "mixed" code ( eventually up to the detail of class / method declaration, or statement ) and comments. Since you are not looking for an exhaustive parse tree, the grammar will stay simple. Then, you'll have a list of tokens that makes sense. Of course, it still uses the messy file_get_contents(__FILE__) approach... But I can't get rid of that, since everything in here is based on source code, not PHP logical structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DocComments distinguish themselves by saying something about how your classes are to be used, compared to regular comments that could assist a developer in reading the code. That's also why the method isn't called `getComment()` instead.

Of course it's all text parsing, and someone just made a choice in docComments always being these multiline comments, but that choice has apparently been made, and reading regular comments is not something in the reflection category.

Comment: Thanks **C.Evenhuis**; Well, that's unfortunate. I was curious because in my reading I heard about the PHP **XP Framework** supporting it, but after digging, I learned they had implemented their own reflection classes, which presumably adds support for it. http://docs.xp-framework.net/xml/doc?core/reflection

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to do just a you a few days ago, and here is my trick. You can just use the php internal tokenizer ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php ) , and then walk the array returned to select only the comments, here is a sample code :

```
$a = token_get_all(file_get_contents('path/to/your/file.php'));
print_r($a); // display an array of all tokens found in the file file.php
```

Here is a list of all tokens php recognize : http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

And the comment you will get by this method include ( from php.net site ) :

T_COMMENT : // or #, and /* */ in PHP 5

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks **dader51**; That's great, except that its using the messy `file_get_contents(__FILE__)` approach for self reflection, and would be difficult to associate a given comment with a definition (class, function, etc.)

Comment: Yes I know for the file_get_contents issue, moreover using the tokenizer for this purpose will bring you to the field of parsing, which is in fact a whole country...

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, for a comment to become documentation it is needed to start with /** not even with standard multi-line comment.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read [here](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php) in the first User Contributed Note:

> The doc comment (`T_DOC_COMMENT`) must begin with a `/**` - that's two asterisks, not one. The comment continues until the first `*/`. A normal multi-line comment `/*...*/` (`T_COMMENT`) does not count as a doc comment.

So only `/** */` blocks are given by this method.

I don't know any other method with php to get the other comments as using `file_get_contents` and filter the comments with e.g. a `regex`

Comment: Thanks **Wessel Kranenborg**; Darn. I had seen that mentioned elsewhere, I just didn't know if there was unmentioned support for non-doc-block comments. PHP should consolidate the user-comments on class methods when the comments are regarding an extended method, since `getDocComment` appears 3 times. I understand it's context, but still.

Answer (score 2):

A doc comment as the name implies, is a documentation comment, not a standard comment, otherwise when you are grabbing comments for apps such as doxygen it will try to document any commented code from testing/debuggung, etc, which often gets left behind and is not important to the user of the API.